# Android: id never declared anywhere but exist?

Tags: android

I examine code example from FragmentBasics.zip

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

There was this code (MainActivity.java):

```
ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);
```

But I never find ***article_fragment*** declared/set anywhere in the whole classes or layouts(xml) or values.  Where does it come from??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the XML code used in `res\layout-large\news_articles.xml`:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
          android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
          android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The `fragment` with the `android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment` attribute has the id set as: `@+id/article_fragment`

The JAVA code where you find the id `article_fragment` being used is on **line 55** for this method: `public void onArticleSelected(int position)`. It checks if your are using a *two-pane layout*. That is why the XML file mentioned at the top, is in the `layout-large` foldr (In the example).

Comment: Thanks.  My bad, I didn't check the large one.  
But then in this _italic_two-pane_italic_ the fragment is not 'dynamically' added to a viewGroup, instead it's predefined in a layout (xml).

Comment: @mamba: The _container_ is predefined in the layout XML. The _fragment_, however, is still being added dynamically. Check the `ArticleFragment` class for the correlation between the two classes the `MainActivity` and the `ArticleFragment` classes.

Answer (score 1):

`R.id.article_fragment` layout is used for large screen device in current example 
you can find out  this layout inside `res/layout-large/news_articles.xml`

Comment: I see.  My bad, I didn't check the large one.

Answer (score 1):

Check  the ArticleFragment class in the Project.That class is extend the Fragement and in that class they are inflating xml named article_view.xml.

So,basically they are finding the ID of that class which is extends the Fragment.